# What is the difference between push branch and merge to master then push?

Tags: git

One way:

```
git checkout myBranch
git push origin myBranch:master
```

Another way:

```
git checkout master
git merge myBranch
git push
```

What is difference between these two?

Comment: A more important question: ***what are you trying to do, and why?***

Comment: I just want to merge my changes into remote master. But I do not know if there is any risk that I could over write some new commits in remote master.

Comment: In the case of `git push origin myBranch:master`, it's fast-forward only, as long as you don't add a plus `+` to the refspec like `+myBranch:master`, which then allows forced updates. Similarly, `git push` is fast-forward, non-forced update only, just don't pass the force flag `-f`.

Comment: I hope I was able to answer your questions clearly. Basically, both of the examples you give above are safe to push to your remote `master`, in the sense that neither of them will overwrite work there, and cause you to lose work.

Comment: @Cupcake Thank you. I have voted your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This:

```
git checkout myBranch
git push origin myBranch:master
```

just attempts to do a fast-forward (i.e. non-forced update) push of `myBranch` to `master`. If `master` is reachable from `myBranch`, i.e. `master` doesn't contain any commits that `myBranch` doesn't also have, then the push will succeed; otherwise, the push will be rejected.

The preceding `git checkout myBranch` is irrelevant to the `git push`, since you're using the refspec `myBranch:master`. You can learn more about refspecs at [Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html).

This:

```
git checkout master
git merge myBranch
git push
```

actually merges `myBranch` into `master`, and then attempts to push it to a remote (with a default configuration of a Git repo, the remote will be origin).

Because `myBranch` is actually merged into `master`, then assuming the remote `master` is behind the local one, i.e. it doesn't contain commits that the local one doesn't also have, then the push will succeed, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: But note that `git merge` might still result in a fast-forward merge. So the end result might or might not be the same, depending on the relationship between master, origin/master and myBranch

Comment: @knittl I'm aware that `git merge myBranch` might be a fast-forward. I didn't bring it up though, because (1) say it is a fast-forward. Then `git push myBranch:master` and `git push origin` are the same. But then (2), let's say that `git merge myBranch` is not a fast-forward. At this point, if the user does `git push origin myBranch:master`, it's the same update that would result from `git push origin`: both fast-forward the remote branch. So it's still the same.

Comment: @Cupcake So basicily, no matter fast-forward or not, my two ways result the same?

Comment: @Magicloud it depends on what the state of `myBranch` is in your first example. You should clarify your question. ***What are you trying to do?*** Also, `git checkout myBranch` doesn't actually have any effect on what you push in your first example.

Comment: @Cupcake Ah, by 'git checkout myBranch', I just wanted to say that 'now I am editing files of myBranch'. It did not mean create a branch or something.